# Getting iOS Action Extension template to work

Tags: ios

I am trying out Action Extensions on iOS. I created a new project and I loaded the action Extension template. Looking at the template code, it seems that if you select an image it will load it into the ActionViewController's imageView. 
I ran the Action extension and it got loaded in share dialogue as expected, but when I selected an image it did not show up in the imageView of ActionViewController. Could someone familiar with Action Extensions let me know what I am missing. 
With thanks 
Reza

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working on Swift Project ,In **ActionViewController u need to retrieve Image from URL

U need to Add the code Like this

```
if let strongImageView = weakImageView {
  if let imageURL = image as? NSURL{
    strongImageView.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: imageURL)!)
     }else{
        strongImageView.image = image as? UIImage 
      }


    }
```

For Clarification I added full Code below (ActionViewController) ,Please Go through the Code ,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Get the item[s] we're handling from the extension context.

    // For example, look for an image and place it into an image view.
    // Replace this with something appropriate for the type[s] your extension supports.
    var imageFound = false
    for item: AnyObject in self.extensionContext!.inputItems {
        let inputItem = item as! NSExtensionItem
        for provider: AnyObject in inputItem.attachments! {
            let itemProvider = provider as! NSItemProvider
            if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as String) {
                // This is an image. We'll load it, then place it in our image view.
                weak var weakImageView = self.imageView
                itemProvider.loadItemForTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as String, options: nil, completionHandler: { (image, error) in
                    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {


                    if let strongImageView = weakImageView {

                           if let imageURL = image as? NSURL{

                     strongImageView.image = UIImage(data:NSData(contentsOfURL: imageURL)!)

                            }else{

                              strongImageView.image = image as? UIImage
                            }

                        }


                    }
                })

                imageFound = true
                break
            }
        }

        if (imageFound) {
            // We only handle one image, so stop looking for more.
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting a little, I found that if I created my test project and Action Extension in Objective-C rather than swift it worked as expected